# How to Rotate mouse in circular shape in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to make an application for cursor movement in which if user enter any number let say 5  & select one shape (Circle or Square): then the mouse cursor must rotate 5 times making that selected shape.

I am getting error :

> cursor.setPos((pos[0] + 1, pos[1] + 1)) 
>   TypeError: 'QPoint' object does not support indexing.

This is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        lblText = QtGui.QLabel("Enter Number: ", self)
        numText = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        btncir = QtGui.QPushButton('Circle', self)
        btncir.setToolTip('Press this button to rotate mouse in circle')

        btnsqr = QtGui.QPushButton('Square', self)
        btnsqr.setToolTip('Press this button to rotate mouse in square')

        fbox = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        fbox.addRow(lblText, numText)
        fbox.addRow(btncir, btnsqr)

        self.setLayout(fbox)

        cursor = QtGui.QCursor()
        pos = cursor.pos()
        cursor.setPos((pos[0] + 1, pos[1] + 1))

        self.setWindowTitle('Move Cursor')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you receive when you have `pos = cursor.pos()` is a `QPoint` instance. To receive the position of the `QPoint`, you need to extract it using

```
 x,y = pos.x(), pos.y()
```

see also [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcursor.html#pos) and [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpoint.html). So in your code example you probably want to do

```
cursor.setPos(pos.x() + 1, pos.y() + 1)
```

About your rotating cursor. As far as I understand you want the cursor to move in a circle. Here is a small example how this can be achieved

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.lblText = QtGui.QLabel("Enter Number: ", self)
        self.numText = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        self.btncir = QtGui.QPushButton('Circle', self)
        self.btncir.setToolTip('Press this button to rotate mouse in circle')
        self.btncir.connect(self.btncir, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.circleClicked)

        self.btnsqr = QtGui.QPushButton('Square', self)
        self.btnsqr.setToolTip('Press this button to rotate mouse in square')

        fbox = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        fbox.addRow(self.lblText, self.numText)
        fbox.addRow(self.btncir, self.btnsqr)

        self.setLayout(fbox)

        self.cursor = QtGui.QCursor()

        self.setWindowTitle('Move Cursor')
        self.show()

    def circleClicked(self):

        # Grab number of rotations
        n=int(str(self.numText.text()))

        # Define circle
        angle=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,50)
        radius=10.

        # Get Cursor
        pos = self.cursor.pos()
        X=pos.x()
        Y=pos.y()

        # Loop through repitions
        for i in range(n):

            # Loop through angles
            for phi in angle:

                # New coordinate
                x=X+radius*np.cos(phi)
                y=Y+radius*np.sin(phi)

                # Update position
                self.cursor.setPos(x,y)

                # Sleep a bit so we can see the movement
                time.sleep(0.01)
```

Note that I made all widgets attributes of `Example`, which makes it easier to access them in methods of `Example`. Also note that `QCursor.setPos` does not take a `tuple`, but two integers as input.

Comment: Thanks for your time , But by adding this it again giving me error.. 
Error:
cursor.setPos((pos.x + 100, pos.y + 100))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

My main aim is to anyhow rotate the cursor in circular motion. Can you help me in that. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: You received the error because I made a mistake. ``pos.x`` returns the method, ``pos.x()`` the value. I made an edit and wrote a little example for you.

Comment: I tried to run the code made by u.. it executed with no errors but I didnt get any output.
I imported these library to run that code : 

import numpy as np
import time

did I imported correct libraries?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help... Which class should I import for " time.sleep " I imported Datetime. Because of that I am getting error. Error: in circleClicked --- time.sleep(0.01),  AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'sleep'

Comment: ``import time``

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks for your help .. Its working .. :D :D

Comment: Need 1 more favor. I didnt get the concept of angle. Can you please let me know .. If i want to make any other shape then I have to change angle & the cordinates that are making circle Right??

Comment: So ``angle`` is an array going from -pi to pi, so once around the circle. We then use it to compute the displacement of the cursor using [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). And yes, if you want to have a square, probably a maximum norm over (x,y) would be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the concept of angle. Thanks you very much.. This really helped me a lot. Hope it works for square too.